https certificate issue on Android
I have a macro made with Macrodroid which I use to make Get http requests. This macro obtains day color electrical contract (in France)
Get https://www.api-couleur-tempo.fr/api/jourTempo/today
this macro worked very well but now when it runs I have an error:

"java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: trust anchor for certification path not found"

I thought it could be du to an change on the server, but when I use this Get with "Postman" it works well!
so it seems it's a problem from Android but I don't know what to do...
I tried it on an other android phone and it works too so I probably have something to do on my phone, but I don't know what!
Can someone help me?
here is Postman request

And here my Macrodroid macro


How old is the device having problem? Maybe you need to force an update of "ISRG Root X1" certificate on it.
